# WickedPDF not working in production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, wkhtmltopdf

I am using wicked_pdf gem, it works fine in local machine, but in server its not working.

I have checked the process of wkhtmltopdf, It tries to run follwoing command

```
/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf -q file:///tmp/wicked_pdf20150609-25535-im12hx.html tmp/wicked_pdf_xxx.pdf
```

When I run this command in server, I get this exception

```
Unable to load library icui18n "Cannot load library icui18n: (icui18n: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)"
```

I installed libicu48 package from here https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/amd64/libicu48/4.8.1.1-13+nmu1ubuntu1

After this following command takes long time

```
/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf -q file:///tmp/wicked_pdf20150609-25535-im12hx.html tmp/wicked_pdf_xxx.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

I have removed "bootstrap.css" from PDF generation. Now its working fine